# Typescript interface for a function that returns a function

Tags: typescript, currying

I have a `StoryOptions` object, that one of its properties is `actionFn`, which when called, will return a function. (I'm making use of [function currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)).

This `actionFn` needs to accept an object of type `ActionBundle`, and it will return a function that accepts a `Payload` and returns a `ReduxAction`.

How do I define the `StoryOptions` interface in typescript?

I have tried:

```
interface StoryOptions {
    baseName: string; 
    actionFn(actions: ActionBundle): ((payload: Payload): ReduxAction); 
}
```

But this tells me:

> 'ReduxAction' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show that it is a function this way:

```
interface StoryOptions {
    baseName: string; 
    actionFn(actions: ActionBundle): ((payload: Payload) => ReduxAction); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
interface StoryOptions {
  actionFn(actions: ActionBundle): (payload: Payload) => ReduxAction; 
}
```

Two ways you can specify a *callable* interface in TS.

```
type Callable = { (...args: any[]): any }
// or
type Callable = (...args: any[]) => any
```

With 1st syntax, the surrounding `{ }` is required. That's what you missed.